# Normalise table in Entity Framework Core and migrate existing data

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

Let's suppose I have a table called `Surveys (SurveyId, ... , SubmittedDate, LastEditedDate)`

It's full of data and I now realise I should normalise it to get audit data into its own table, so I create a table `SurveyAudits (SurveyAuditId, SubmittedDate, LastEditedDate)`

1. When I create the table, I want to populate it with the data from `Surveys`.
2. Then I need to add a foreign key to `Surveys` (SurveyAuditId) so each survey links to its `SurveyAudit`.
3. Finally, I can drop the redundant columns from `Surveys` (SubmittedDate, LastEditedDate)

What do I add to the Up method to achieve this?

I suspect my approach so far may be unsuitable, so please steer me onto the correct path if that is the case!

Code:

```
public partial class CreateSurveyAudit : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "SurveyAudits",
            columns: table => new
            {
                SurveyAuditId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false).Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy",SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),                    
                SubmittedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                LastEditedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false)                    
            },

//I could get the data into the new table like so, but I would not have the relationship:

        migrationBuilder.Sql("INSERT INTO SurveyAudits(SubmittedDate, LastEditedDate) 
                           SELECT SubmittedDate, LastEditedDate FROM Surveys")

//so perhaps I could add the foreign key column first

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(...);
        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(...);
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(...);

//then something like...
       foreach (var survey in context.Surveys) { //but how do I access context?
       survey.Add(new SurveyAudit(
                         SubmittedDate = survey.SubmittedDate,
                         LastEditedDate = survey.LastEditedDate)
       }
       context.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `SurveyId` column on your `SurveyAudits` table to make a relationship

Then use the following:

```
    migrationBuilder.Sql("INSERT INTO SurveyAudits(SurveyId, SubmittedDate, LastEditedDate)
                          SELECT SurveyId, SubmittedDate, LastEditedDate FROM Surveys")
```

Comment: But the relationship is on the wrong side then. A Survey has a SurveyAudit so Survey needs to have SurveyAuditId as a foreign key, rather than SurveyAudit have SurveyId as a foreign key.